# Magento, insert value in a custom attribute after save products

Tags: php, magento, insertafter

I've created a custom attribute for products in Magento, I want insert this value after the product is saved, because I must insert a code that read the field weight and calculate the price of spedition for that. I need that value because I must send that value in a module for eBay that takes all value in products when I launch it. I am a beginner in Magento. So do you have some code, info or other that can help me, how I can do that?

Comment: What have you already tried? SO won't write your code for you. Give it an honest attempt and, if you can't figure it out, come back and edit your question to include your code with the specific problem you're facing.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use `catalog_product_save_after` event which trigger after product saves . you can listen this event and get all product data and you can set any attribute value from there.

Comment: hi rohit, thanks for the answer u have some code of example, i must create an extension or what? thanks in advance iam beginner in magento!